# Windows Terminal Not Picking up PATH variable

Tags: command-line, powershell, terminal, windows-11, windows-terminal

I'm using the latest Windows Terminal + Windows 11 + Powershell 7, and I came accross a very strange problem all of a sudden. I'm getting very weird behavior from windows terminal, after restarts, shutdowns and everything:

- It's no picking anything up from the PATH variable. Although `$env:path.Split(";")` lists them up, with all the required folders included system32 and windows. So writing `ipconfig` for example gets me `The term inconfig is not recognizable`
- Even browsing to \Windows\System32 and writing `ipconfig` in the terminal gets me the `The term ipconfig is not recognizable`
- Only way to launch it is navigating to the `system32` directory and adding .exe, so `ipconfig.exe`. And while it opens up, it does it in a new window so its useless. The same goes for all other commands, `netstat`, `dotnet`, etc.

Not sure what would be the issue, anyone faced something like this before?

- Built-in commands like `dir` or `ls` works as expected.
- I tried another terminal, the git bash for example, and things like `ipconfig` works as expected.

Below is my path for reference. I also removed everything except `C:\Windows\System32` to test things out, but still got the same behavior, ipconfig as an example was not launched except when I add the `.exe` and it launches in a new window.

```
C:\Ruby31-x64\bin;
C:\Ruby26-x64\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs;
C:\Program Files\Git\bin;
C:\Users\Yehia\scoop\shims;
C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;
C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\tools;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache\ant-1.9.4\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\platform-tools;
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;
C:\Python27;
C:\Python27\Scripts;
C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;
C:\xampp-8.1\php;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
C:\Gradle\gradle-4.8.1\bin;
C:\Users\Yehia\.dotnet\tools;
C:\Program Files\Oracle Instant Client;
C:\Users\Yehia.000\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;
C:\Program Files\Ngrok;
%USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools;
C:\Stripe;
C:\Users\Yehia\AppData\Roaming\npm;
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
```

[image]

Comment: Search all instances of `ipconfig.exe` on your computer, to find if it is found in another path than system32.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly did you show the path value? Copy & paste the output of `$Env:Path` in your PS window *as text*. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @harrymc It is in system32 folder, same for netstat for example and others

Comment: Hi @Bodo, It's all in the question. Path value were printed using $env:path.Split(";"), and the output is listed in the question in text.

Comment: The screenshot of the error message shows an image of text. When I use `$env:path.Split(";")` I get the path elements without trailing `;` and it doesn't contain unexpanded variables.

Comment: @Bodo There is, right before the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a couple of hours, the issue turned out to be the PATHEXT system variable. It should be `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`. However, its seems like an application messed it up and changed it to `%PATHEXT;.RB%`, probably something related to ruby.

Comment: Programs modifying PATHEXT is troubling. Especially from programmers that don't understand Windows or it's security.